# Mongoose aggregate $sum returning zero

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate function like so:

```
var match = {};
match["products.totalprice"] = {$exists:true};

var project = {};
    project["_id"] = 0
    project["products.totalprice"] = 1;
    project["line"] = "$products.closedate";

ThisCollection.aggregate([
    {$match: match},
    {$project: project},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$line",
        total: {$sum: {$ifNull: ["$products.totalprice", 0]}}
    }}

], function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
});
```

My schema is essentially a name and _id field with a nested array of products with totalprice, closedate and some other fields:

```
db.data.save({name:"a",products:{totalprice:1,closedate:1,...}})
db.data.save({name:"b",products:{totalprice:2,closedate:2,...}})
```

and the Schemas look like:

```
var Products = new Schema({
    totalprice: Number,
    closedate: Date,
    otherRandomFields: ...
}) 

var ThisCollection = new Schema({
    name: String, 
    products:[Products]
});
```

`docs` is returning the date objects I expect to see, but total is always 0.

I'm checking `$exists` and `$ifNull` as I saw suggested somewhere (but can't seem to find now). I've also confirmed that `products.totalprice` is of type `Number` in my schema.

Does anything jump out at anyone as incorrect?

**Edit**

Actual (piece of) output from running this function:

```
0: {_id: ["2014-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"], total: 0}
1: {_id: ["2014-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"], total: 0}
2: {_id: ["2014-02-01T05:00:00.000Z"], total: 0}
```

Is it odd that `_id` returns an array?

**More Information**

Thought this might have been an issue with `$sum`, so tried some other methods like `$first` and `$push` - here's the output from `$push`:

```
0: {_id: "2014-01-01T05:00:00.000Z", total: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
1: {_id: "2014-01-31T05:00:00.000Z", total: [0, 0, 0]}
2: {_id: "2014-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", total: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could edit your question to include some sample documents and the expected output from the aggregation.

Comment: @chridam I added some details. I have hundreds of thousands of actual documents stored. I'm expecting to see the `_id` as `products.closedate` being aggregated on, and `total` should be a sum of `products.totalprice` from each `products.closedate`.

Comment: @chridam I'm getting the `_id` field as `products.closedate` as expected, but the corresponding `total` fields always returns `0`

Comment: Shouldn't this line `match["product.totalprice"] = {$exists:true};` be `match["products.totalprice"] = {$exists:true};`?

Comment: @chridam Fixed. (my actual functions are dynamically generated and my code is a lot longer, I'm attempting to be as true in this example as possible)

Comment: What are you grouping by? Are you grouping by day or by the full datetime?

Comment: @chridam Full datetime, but all the datetimes saved in this example are y/m/d, no times, so the datetimes appear to be aggregating as expected in the returned data. It's simply that the totalprice fields associated with them are not summing as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following aggregation pipeline, it extracts the **`$year`**, **`$month`**, **`$dayOfMonth`** from your date and then use those as the group by key. Also, the logic for checking if the field exists and assigning it a value should ideally be done in the **`$project`** pipeline as this enables you to easily debug your pipeline operation and code is readable:

```
var match = {};
match["products.totalprice"] = {$exists:true};

var project = {};
    project["_id"] = 0;        
    project["line"] = {
        "year": { "$year": "$products.closedate" },
        "month": { "$month": "$products.closedate" },
        "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$products.closedate" }
    };
    project["total"] = {
        "$ifNull": [ "$products.totalprice", 0 ]
    }

ThisCollection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$products"},
    {$match: match},
    {$project: project},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$line",
        total: { $sum: "$total" }
    }}

], function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
});
```

The is the `$unwind` property, otherwise it is trying to sum together arrays returned by `$total`.

Comment: The `project["line"]` statement doesn't appear to work (doc returns `undefined`) but without that, the totalpriceExists seems to be working. Doing some testing...

Comment: This is returning the total number of records matched by date, but not the sum of the actual totalprice field.

Comment: I updated your answer. This works, except for the group by year/month/day fields. That's not part of the OP, **BUT** I would actually like to get that part working, it's very useful.